# Is network configuration necessary for ethernet?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu system to the internet using Ethernet cables. Do I need to change any settings from the defaults? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP dynamically(DHCP) assign IP address and has no MAC filtering or ISP has your original MAC then you do not need to do anything after install ubuntu. Even ubuntu will detect your internet connection during installation. So don't worry about this.

If you have static IP (isp provided) then you just need to add them in network connection which is easy and default installed.

[image]

If your ISP provide a MAC (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX) then add this in cloned MAC address section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your network is using DHCP, then no. However, I recommend setting your DNS servers to `8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` to use Google Public DNS.